# Length of the longest sorted subsequence

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, subsequence

My unsorted array is

```
string[] a = new string[] { "10", "22", "9", "33", "21", "50", "41", "60", "80" };
```

In this array, `10,22,33,50,60,80` are in ascending order,
so the output must be `6`.

In general, I want the longest possible length of an ascending list made from elements of the array and starting with the first element.

I have tried this :

```
string[] a = new string[] { "10", "22", "9", "33", "21", "50", "41", "60", "80" };
List<int> res = new List<int>();
int arrLength = a.Length;
int i = 0;
int prev;
while (i < arrLength)
{
    if (i < arrLength)
    {
        res.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a[i]));
        prev = Convert.ToInt32(a[i]);
        while (Convert.ToInt32(a[++i]) < prev) { }
    }
}

int asdf = res.Count;
```

but did not succeed.

Answer (score 4):

This is called the [*Longest Ascending Subsequence*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) problem. You can find it using a simple dynamic programming algorithm described in the article.

If all you need is the length of the longest subsequence, you can do it like this:

```
// length[i] is the length of subsequence ending at position i
var length = new int[a.Length];
for (var i = 0 ; i != length.Length ; i++) {
    // In the worst case a number ends a subsequence of length 1
    length[i] = 1;
    var ai = Convert.ToInt32(a[i]);
    // Go backward on the items that we've seen before
    for (var j = i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--) {
        var aj = Convert.ToInt32(a[i]);
        // If number at i is greater than the number at j, use the length of j's longest subsequence
        // to calculate the length of the sequence for element at i.
        if (aj > ai && length[j]+1 > length[i]) {
            length[i] = length[j]+1;
        }
    }
}
var res = length.Max();
```

Your algorithm is incorrect because it uses a "greedy strategy", i.e. it considers any number greater than the previously found one a part of the sorted sequence.

Comment: This doesn't look right: `for (var j = i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j++)`.  Is that supposed to be decrementing `j`?

Comment: I think this can be solved way easier (with one loop).

Comment: @FabianBigler No, you cannot solve it correctly in linear time (test your code on the input `1, 100, 2, 3, 4, 5` to see why).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I also answered the question. Dont you think this is faster?

Comment: @FabianBigler Try it out on the sequence above. The correct answer is 5, one-loop solution would produce 4.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah no. I thought you have to start counting after each subsequence. but it's summing them up. my bad.

Comment: @RameshRajendran By _longest_ ascending sequence, we're literally trying to find the _longest_ sequence possible.  `1, 100` is not the _longest_ sequence in that set of data.  `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` is.

Comment: @JohnH , But the OP Said in a command ` I am always start from the first element`

Comment: @RameshRajendran `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` still starts from the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You could face problems with this even when you do manager to get it counting correctly.

What if there are more than one ordered set of values to discover, do you want to discover both or just the first one or the one starting with the lowest number etc?

What you need to do first is take the array and create a copy of it in the order you need. You then need to perform checks against the unordered array looping through and comparing the values to the ordered array and breaking out the loop when ordering stops. But you still need to consider the other aspects of what data you want to obtain from doing this and include it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Homework? This is a textbook example of a problem that can be solved using [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). The array `longest` will hold the longest increasing subseries ending with the element on the same position.

```
public int LongestIncreasingSubseries(int[] input)
{
  int[] longest = new int[input.Length];
  int result = 1;
  for(int i = 0; i<input.Length; ++i) 
  {
    longest[i] = 1;
    for(j=0; j<i; ++j) if (input[j]<input[i] && longest[j]+1>longest[i]) longest[i] = longest[j]+1;
    if(longest[j]>result) result = longest[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arr = new string[] { "10", "22", "9", "33", "21", "50", "41", "60", "80" };
int biggest = int.MinValue;
int current = 0;

int count = (from str in arr
             where int.TryParse(str, out current)
             let number = current
             where number > biggest
             select biggest = number).Count();
```

this LINQ query takes each string, and try to convert it into a number. if it succeed, it checks if the number is bigger than the last biggest number. if it does - than storing that number as the new biggest number - and return it.

the `Count` method just count how much items had returned (but you could store them in an array, or iterating on them in a foreach loop, or anything).

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer.

It is easy to undersand you

```
string[] a = new string[] { "10", "22", "9", "33", "21", "50", "41", "60", "80" };
        List<int> res = new List<int>();
        int arrLength = a.Length;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
        {
            if (i < arrLength)
            {
                if (res.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(a[i]) > res[res.Count - 1])
                    {
                        res.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a[i]));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    res.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a[i]));
                }
            }
        }

        int asdf = res.Count;
```

And the output is 6

See this [image: screen short]

and you can download my code [here](https://ideone.com/BATFFy)

Comment: Please do not comment on other people's posts just to tell them to read your answer. This is spam, and it is not appropriate. Please read the [rules about comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) — comments are meant to let others know of a temporary issue (e.g. “there's a bug that you should fix”) or to ask small follow-up questions (e.g. “Your second sentence is unclear, did you mean <this> or <that>?”).